# Change data binded?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-components

Is there a way in Angular 2 to change the data binded to an element by ngModel ?
For example :

```
<input [(ngModel)]="color" />
```

How stop binding color, and bind color2 (for example) and the input ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a function to achieve this behavior. Something like:

my.component.ts

```
...
getModelValue(){
    if(contidionA){
        return colorA;
    } else {
        return colorB;
    }
}
...
```

my.component.html

```
<input [(ngModel)]="getModelValue()" />
```